# execute button click inside user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have created a user control in asp.net which contains a form and a button which saves the data. So when the popup loads the user control is inside. I click on the button to save the form data and the click event is not fired?

this is a jquery popup below with the user control inside.

```
<div id="dialog_form"  title="Create new user">
   <uc1:SettingsPopUp runat="server"  />
</div>
```

here is the user control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SettingsPopUp.ascx.cs" Inherits="FRDashboard.Content.Dashboards.SettingsPopUp" %>
<link href="../../Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Styles/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>



<div id="divChartSettings" runat="server">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_chart_settings" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
//FORM ELEMENTS GO HERE
     <asp:Button ID="applySettings" runat="server" OnCommand="applyChartSettings_Click" EnableViewState="true" Text="Save" CssClass="button" />
      <asp:Label ID="lbl_message" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code for the user control?

Comment: Added user control code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. The user control was in a JQuery UI popup which was stopping the postback. The following fixed the problem:

```
 dialog.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your aspx page,

```
<uc1:SettingsPopUp runat="server" /> to

<uc1:SettingsPopUp runat="server"  ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

Because you are using the button control inside an *asp:UpdatePanel*.

Comment: this still does not fire the event

Comment: @Chris can you update the question with the full code of the aspx page, which contains the user control